# Creating a Team on BIM 360 Design Collaboration

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-bim360

Could someone please point out the endpoint that can create teams on BIM 360 Design Collaboration?
I'm looking to do what the "Add Team" button does in the UI:

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B0or4.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is no API support for Design Collaboration at this moment. But we're listening to customers' voices. May I know why you want to use API to create teams? Do you have any special workflow or use cases? I can help you pass to our engineering team to evaluate the possibility. If the info. you want to provide cannot be posted publicly, please send to forge[DOT]help[AT]autodesk[DOT]com.

**Note.** Please don't provide any confidential information to us.

Thanks